# iOS: custom font not displaying special characters correctly

Tags: ios, fonts, special-characters, truetype

In an iOS app I have problems with special characters like german umlauts and others when using a certain font, with wrong characters being displayed as the result.

The font name is "*MetroflexUniMedium*". I have tried ttf and otf format. The font originally came in "Font Suitcase" format, I converted it with FontXChange.

**All** other fonts I tried work, and I the problem also appears when using hard coded strings, so this should not be a problem with character encoding. Also the problem does not appear in other programs, e.g. in Photoshop I can use all the special characters I need with this font.

The problem appears on all iOS versions that support custom fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. When converting the font to ttf for the first time, I did not set the encoding explicitly to utf8 so FontXChange selected a different encoding. So setting the encoding to utf8 in the preferences of FontXChange solved the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with Czech language to display the special characters (only with capitals). But I can't find the UTF8 encoding option in the preferences of FontXChange 3.0.0. These are the options I have: http://cl.ly/image/1j122x2u1l22 
Is it one of these?

Comment: After a quick look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#History I think you should try "Unicode".

Comment: I found what caused my problem and it was not the font. My label was too small to display the special characters on top of capital letters. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @Marc-AndréWeibezahn in my case "Åland Islands" is not proper display in country list. so please give me a solution for this.Thanks..

Comment: Same I had similar issue i had used custom font with .ttf or .otf Normaly font looks good but special character not looks good. And Yes it worked with UI Lable but not work with Table  Cell.TextLable.  Please help me..... :(

Comment: @Mayur are you sure that the characters are supported by your custom font?

Comment: @Marc-AndréWeibezahn Yes.As my client provide me this font he told me that. I said him that this should be the font issue but he said its not font issue.